# StaleState exception org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa

Please do not close this as duplicate. There are many links about this issue but this is different. I can't put the code here. I can explain the scenario

A part of my code does save and delete using jpa/hibernate in java. I run this application on AWS environment with application in server A1 and sqlserver database in D1. I see every time when I click a specific button, it does some dml operations but the after the method ends, it throws the above stated exception. But I see that the rows are modified and could still see an error

To check it I installed a local application (A2) and database (D2) servers and it worked fine. I connect my local application (A2) to D1 server. Surprisingly, I still don't see an issue.

Still wondering how an application server is responsible for this error. If anyone has faced this weird issue, please help. Here is the stacktrace

Thanks!!

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:81)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:73)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatch.java:151)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:128)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatch.java:111)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.execute(AbstractBatchImpl.java:163)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.executeBatch(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:226)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:482)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
... 130 common frames omitted
 Wrapped by: org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:297)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:221)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:765)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:734)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:518)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1125.createUserSession(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: do you see the error consistently?

Comment: Yes.It is highly consistent.

Comment: Are you using optimistic locking  (`Wrapped by: org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException`) and if yes, which column annotated  with `@Version`. Are you deploying application in multiple instances?  On side note, it is tough to tell what caused failure without code.

Comment: @srinivasvishnu And did you find a solution?